# MySQL join error

Tags: mysql, sql, join

The following query gives me an error in phpmyadmin. It looks syntactically correct to me, and the table/column names match up accordingly. I have tried a number of variations (quoting table names, using as, etc) with no luck.

```
SELECT *
FROM GROUP
INNER JOIN GROUP_MEMBER ON GROUP.group_id = GROUP_MEMBER.group_id
WHERE group_owner='test';
```

Error I'm getting:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP INNER JOIN GROUP_MEMBER ON GROUP.group_id = GROUP_MEMBER.group_id WHERE ' at line 2

Comment: group is a reserved keyword. try \`group\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"group" is a sql-keyword, you need to surround it with backticks if you want to use it as tablename.

Comment: Ah duh, can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP` is a reserved word in SQL so it's a bad choice for a table name.  If you surround it with backticks it might work but I'd really recommend changing that table name.

```
SELECT *
FROM `GROUP`
INNER JOIN GROUP_MEMBER ON `GROUP`.group_id = GROUP_MEMBER.group_id
WHERE group_owner='test';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not PHPMyAdmin-specfiic error.  The problem you have is using a table name `GROUP` that matches a MySQL reserved word. If you insist on using such a problematic table name, you need to enclose it with backticks anywhere you might use it.

```
SELECT *
FROM `GROUP`
INNER JOIN GROUP_MEMBER ON `GROUP`.group_id = GROUP_MEMBER.group_id
WHERE group_owner='test';
```